# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}>\frac{3}{5}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question is to check if : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}>\frac{3}{5}$

the problem is that i am sure that this series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}$ is convergent (if it is not then i would be very happy as i will then be done.)

I would be thankful if someone can help me out with solving this.

Comment: C'mon....this is exponential series. It's just $ log(2) -1 $ and I'm afraid the result is false.

Comment: Ok, $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$.. $e^x-1=x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$.. $e^{\log \log2}-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}$..$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}=log2-1$.. Is this correct???

Comment: yeah ....I guess so... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Think about the Taylor expansion of Exp[x]; this could help you answering both questions.

Comment: both questions???

Comment: Well, yes @PraphullaKoushik : the question about the value of the series and the more hidden yet still existing question about the series' convergence.